# how to send message from one spring application to another using JMS

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-jms

I need to send message from one spring-boot application to another spring-boot application using JMS

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring Integration's `JmsTemplate` and `MessageListener` to do this.

Take a look at http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/jms.html for more details.